# sql, big query: aggregate all entries between two strings in a variable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I have to solve this problem within bigQuery. I have this column in my table:

```
event            | time
_________________|____________________
start            | 1
end              | 2
random_event_X   | 3
start            | 4 
error_X          | 5 
error_Y          | 6
end              | 7
start            | 8
error_F          | 9
start            | 10
random_event_Y   | 11
error_z          | 12
end              | 13
```

I would like to, from the `end` event record everything until `start` appear and then count it. Everything can happen between start and end and outside of it. If there is an end, there is a start, **but if there is a start, there is not necessarily an end.**

The desire output would be like:

```
string_agg                            | count
"start, end"                          |  1
"start, error_X, error_Y, end"        |  1
"start, random_event_Y error_Z, end"  |  1
```

So everything between each start and end if `start` has an `end`. So without the `random_event_X` at time 3, the `start` at time 8 or the `error_F` at time 9.

I was not able to find the solution and have struggle understanding how to approach this problem. Any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT agg_events, COUNT(1) cnt 
FROM (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(event ORDER BY time) agg_events, COUNTIF(event IN ('start', 'end')) flag   
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(event = 'start') OVER(PARTITION BY grp1 ORDER BY time) grp2     
    FROM (
      SELECT *, COUNTIF(event = 'end') OVER(ORDER BY time DESC) grp1 
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  )
  GROUP BY grp1, grp2
)
WHERE flag = 2
GROUP BY agg_events
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row agg_events                          cnt  
1   start,random_event_Y,error_z,end    1    
2   start,error_X,error_Y,end           1    
3   start,end                           1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets -- this is particularly true in massively parallel, columnar databases such as BigQuery.

So, I have to assume that you have some other column that specifies the ordering.  If so, you can use a cumulative sum to identify the groups and then aggregation:

```
select grp,
       string_agg(event, ',' order by time)
from (select t.*,
             countif(event = 'start') over (order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(time);
```

Note:  I would also advise you to use `array_agg()` instead of `string_agg()`.  Arrays are generally easier to work with than strings.

EDIT:

I see, you only want up to `end`.  In that case, another level of window funtions:

```
select grp,
       string_agg(event, ',' order by <ordering col>)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when event = 'end' then time end) over (partition by grp) as max_end_time
      from (select t.*,
                   countif(event = 'start') over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where max_end_time is null or time <= max_end_time
group by grp
order by min(<ordering col>);
```

Comment: thank you for answering. There is indeed an ordering column which is an UNIX timestamp, I will edit my problem so it includes it.
Concerning the proposed query, it does not record everything between each `start` and `end` of a column. When I apply it, I have an output like `"start, end, event_x, event_A, event_B"` and so on. As precised, a start does not necessarily an end, which makes this problem even harder for me to solve.